# Sidebar Question Stats - Put question stats back in the sidebar

Tags: script, questions

### Screenshot

[image]

### About

A recent change moved question stats (ask date, view count, and active date) from the sidebar to under the question title. Like others, you [may find this distracting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331349/why-are-the-sidebar-stats-for-a-question-now-under-the-title), because the information is only occasionally useful, yet its new position results in it being the *second* thing you read on every page.

This userscript runs on any SE site, and restores the question stats back to their prior position in the sidebar, removing them from just below the title.

This is intended for desktop users. The position change was probably made to make it [easier for those with narrow screens](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323269/) to see the stats. Should work on any browser that supports userscripts and ES6, including Chrome and FF.

For compatibility with [Roomba Forecaster](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Roomba-Forecaster) and with any other older userscripts that depended on the old location of question stats in the sidebar, make sure this userscript runs [before they do](https://www.mturkcrowd.com/threads/how-to-change-execution-order-of-userscripts-and-customize-excluded-pages.152/), so that the `#qinfo` table it creates can be found by the other userscripts.

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/tree/master/Sidebar-Question-Stats)

[Direct install link](https://github.com/CertainPerformance/Stack-Exchange-Userscripts/raw/master/Sidebar-Question-Stats/Sidebar-Question-Stats.user.js)

Comment: Ironically, one of the delays in updating [Roomba Forecaster](https://github.com/makyen/StackExchange-userscripts/tree/master/Roomba-Forecaster) was making sure that it worked regardless of which order the scripts ran in :-). Version 2.2.0 of Roomba Forecaster has been released. It should work with any execution order. However, having Stack Sidebar Question Stats run prior to any other scripts that rely on the old structure of the Sidebar should help quite a bit.

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm willing to go with whatever is most appropriate. My hope had been that CertainPerformance would move the code onto GitHub where it would be possible to submit PRs. When I created it, I'd really hoped/expected my Gist to just be a stopgap. Unfortunately, that hasn't ended up being the case. Thus, I'd used the suggested edits as, effectively, a PR. :-;  If it's more appropriate for me to create an answer, I'm happy to do so.

Comment: @Makyen, the separate answer approach has been used several times here (full disclosure: I've used it often).  But if CertainPerformance is willing to state that you are an approved custodian/editor of his script and this question, then you can keep making edits and I can clear my review alarms in a timely manner without stepping on "bad" suggested edits that are really okay.

Comment: I'll make a repository. I didn't think it'd be necessary for something this small, but it sounds like it's a better approach. Never really used Github before, but I'll learn